# Evaluate the integral $\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-\beta x}dx$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, gamma-function, analytic-continuation

I want to evaluate the following integral $$\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-\beta x}dx$$
where $\beta$ is a complex number.

Now, if $\beta$ was real, we could just set $y = \beta x$ and we will reduce to the Gamma function. Since $\beta$ is complex, though, when I set $y = \beta x$, I am integrating over the line with $\arg \beta$ on the complex plane, so I can't reduce directly to the Gamma function, can I?

I have found after some calculations that $$\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-\beta x}dx = \Gamma(t)\beta^{-t}$$ which is exactly what one would find if it didn't bother with the previous observation.

So my questions are:  Is my observation on the complex line correct? and 2) What is the best way to prove the result?

**My work**

Write $\beta = a + ib$. Consider the integral as a function of $t,a,b$ to get $$I(t,a,b) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-a x}e^{-ibx}dx$$.

Notice that $$\frac{\partial I}{\partial a}(t,a,b) = -I(t+1,a,b)$$ and
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial b}(t,a,b) = -iI(t+1,a,b)$$

Now since $\displaystyle I(t+1) = \frac t{a+ib}I(t)$, the previous two equations become $$\frac{\partial I}{\partial a} = -\frac t{a+ib}I$$ and
$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial b} = -\frac{it}{a+ib}I$$

which put together yield $I(t,a,b) = C(t) (a+ib)^{-t}$.
Also, since $\displaystyle I(t,1,0) = C(t) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}dx= \Gamma(t)$, we get

$$I(t,a,b) = \Gamma(t) (a+ib)^{-t} = \Gamma(t)\beta^{-t}$$

which seems like too much work!

Comment: You can also first prove that the integral is analytic [e.g. using these methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem#Infinite_sums_and_integrals) and then the result follows from analytic continuation being unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct in the result.  To verify this and to provide an instructive way forward, we present here a direct approach the relies on [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).

To that end, we let $I$ be the integral in the complex plane given by

$$I=\oint_C z^{t-1}e^{-\beta z}\,dz$$

where $\text{Re}(\beta)>0$, $t>0$, and $C=C_1+C_2+C_3$ is the contour comprised of the $4$ components

$(i)$ $C_1$ is the real-line segment from $(\epsilon,0)$ to $(R,0)$;

$(ii)$ $C_2$ is the circular arc centered at the origin with radius $R$ from $(R,0)$ to $(R\cos \theta_0,R\sin \theta_0)$ where $\beta e^{i\theta_0}=1 \implies e^{i\theta_0}=\frac{1}{\beta}$.

$(iii)$ $C_3$ is the line segment from $(R\cos \theta_0,R\sin \theta_0)$ to $(\epsilon \cos \theta,\epsilon \sin \theta)$;

$(iv)$ $C_4$ is the circular arc centered at the origin with radius $\epsilon$ from $(\epsilon \cos \theta,\epsilon \sin \theta)$ to $(\epsilon,0)$.

Since $z^{x-1}e^{-\beta z}$ is analytic in $C$, then from Cauchy's Integral Theorem, we have $I=0$.  Moreover, the contributions from $C_2$ and $C_4$ can easily be shown to vanish as $R\to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0$, respectively.

Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
I&=\oint_C z^{t-1}e^{-\beta z}\,dz\\\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}(x)^{t-1}e^{-\beta x}\,dx+\int_\infty^0 (e^{i\theta_0}x)^{t-1}e^{-\beta e^{i\theta_0}x}e^{i\theta_0}dx=0\\\\
\implies \int_0^{\infty}(x)^{t-1}e^{-\beta x}\,dx&=\frac{1}{\beta^{t}}\int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{\beta^{t}}\Gamma(t)
\end{align}$$

which was to be shown!

Comment: veri nice indeed. Thank you! :-)

Comment: @ant Thank you!  Much appreciative.  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

$$ f(\beta) = \int_0^\infty x^{t-1}e^{-\beta x}dx$$
is clearly an analytic function in $\beta$ if $\text{Re}(\beta) > 0$ (differentiate under the integral sign).
$$ g(\beta) = \Gamma(t) \beta^{-t} $$
is also analytic in $\beta$.  Since $f(\beta) = g(\beta)$ for all $\beta \in (0,\infty)$, it follows by the principle of isolated zeros that they must be equal on the intersections of their domains of definition.

Comment: Analytic continuation is one of the coolest things ever. I still get excited whenever I see it in practice.

Comment: I was under the belief that the OP wanted to verify that $f=g$.

Comment: @Dr.MV It is trivial by change of variables if $\beta$ is real, as the OP pointed out.  I used analytic continuation to show it is true for all other $\beta$.

Comment: Your answer states that $f=g$ for all $\beta$, but how does one reach that conclusion immediately.  Perhaps one can say $f=g$ for real $\beta>0$ and then use AC to conclude that $f=g$ for all $\beta$ with positive real part.

Comment: @Dr.MV As it happens, the integral is undefined for the real part of $\beta$ less than or equal to 0.  Nevertheless, it if were defined outside of that range, one could still use analytic continuation.

Comment: thank you! Need to remember it next time :)