# computing $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{itx} dx$ using Cauchy Theorem and gamma function rapresentation

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, gamma-function, cauchy-integral-formula, analytic-continuation

I want to solve the above integral with $t \in \mathbb{R}$; using a software ([Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier%20transform%20calculator&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22transformfunction%22%7D%20-%3E%22t%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable1%22%7D%20-%3E%22t%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C%20%22variable2%22%7D%20-%3E%22w%22)) to verify the result I obtain the following result:
$I(t) \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{itx} dx = -i \frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{itx} dx = -i2\pi \frac{d \delta(t)}{dt}$
To solve it I start rewritting $I(t)$ as:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{itx} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{0} x e^{itx} dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} x e^{itx} dx = -\int_{0}^{\infty} w e^{-itw} dw + \int_{0}^{\infty} y e^{ity} dy $
I tried to solve both the last integrals using [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1399600/evaluate-the-integral-int-0-infty-xt-1e-beta-xdx/1399848#1399848); In my case I have (following the notation of the last link) $\Re(\beta) = 0$, but this shouldn't be a problem, In fact I can write $t = lim_{h \rightarrow 0} t \pm ih$ and interchange the limit with the integral (using [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)).
With this approach I obtain the following result:
$I(t) = -\frac{\Gamma(2)}{(it)^2} + \frac{\Gamma(2)}{(-it)^2}$
which is 0 for all $t$ except for $t=0$ where I have an indeterminate form $-\infty + \infty$.
**Is it correct this solution?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

$$I(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{itx} dx$$
diverges for all $t$. It converges only in the sense of distributions.

$$I_N(t)=\int_{-N}^N x e^{itx} dx=-2i \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\sin(Nt)}{t}$$
$$h(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t 2\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du, \qquad h(Nt)\to 2\pi 1_{t> 0}$$
For all $\phi \in C^\infty_c$
$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty I_N(t)\phi(t)dt=\lim_{N\to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty i\, h(Nt)\phi''(t)dt= \int_{-\infty}^\infty 2i\pi 1_{t>0}\phi''(t)dt=2i\pi\phi'(0)$$
**This is the definition of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{itx} dx$ converges to $-2i\pi\delta'(t)$ in the sense of distributions.**

To use the Gamma function you need to do the same kind of idea, saying that $\lim_{a\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{itx}e^{-a|x|} dx$ converges to $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{itx} dx$ in the sense of distributions.

You'll get (something like) $\lim_{a\to 0} \frac1{(it+a)^2}-\frac1{(it-a)^2}$, the second derivative of $\lim_{a\to 0} \log(it-a)-\log(it+a)=C\ sign(t)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer reuns. So, taking the last limit, I can conclude that, in the sense of distributions, $I(t)$ converges to 0 $\forall t - \{0\}$, right?

Comment: Is $1_{t>0}$ the symbol for the Heaviside step function? I don't understand why $h(Nt) \rightarrow 2 \pi  1_{t>0}$

Comment: Sorry huge typo, $h(t)=\int_{-\infty}^t 2\frac{\sin(u)}{u}du$ so $h(-\infty)=0,h(\infty)=A$ which is found to be $2\pi$ @user1172131